# Is it possible for an app to have several PID at the same time?

Tags: android, linux, multithreading, pid

I have done some experiments and to my knowledge, an app can create several instances of ART (AndroidRunTime) that can execute code concurrently. Each of these instances are called by the same PID than the app. Each of these ART instances can create several threads and these threads have the app PID. But is it possible for an app to have several PID simultaneously? If it is the case could you provide an example?

Comment: An App can have several PID's you can define what process an Activity, Service, Receiver, Provider run in the Android Manifest - all will have the same 'user', but separate PID's.  A use case would be a Media Player app - An Activity is the UI, Playing logic in a Service, if in separate processes then if the Service crashed then it wouldn't crash the Activity, or vice versa.

Comment: You can also launch different activities under different taskAffinities with a newTask intent flag which will then give separate PIDs to those activities of same app as well.

Comment: @Mark Keen. Do you have an app name to give me ? I want to test it, and see it happening. Following your idea of the Media Player, I tested on the VLC app, While playing music, I used 'watch "ps | grep videolan"' and I've seen only one process.

Comment: You can just create a simple app the has one `Activity` and one `Service` - in your manifest have `process=:service_process` or something similar for the `Service - start the `Service` from the `Activity` (launch the test app) and look at the "Debuggable Processes" in the Android Monitor.  You'll see the separate processes - no need for the command line using grep.

Comment: If you concat your first and last comments in an answer to the question, I accept it. Thx.