# Does each application on Android have a single PID?

Tags: android, system-calls, pid, strace

What I understand is that PID is a unique process ID for each running application. Can an application have more than one PID running at the same time and how can we see that from the strace output?

Comment: Related: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Processes

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this SO question doesn't have an answer (if it did, I would have marked this question "duplicate"):

> [Is it possible for an app to have several PID at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898846/)
>
> I have done some experiments and to my knowledge, an app can create
> several instances of ART (AndroidRunTime) that can execute code
> concurrently. Each of these instances are called by the same PID than
> the app. Each of these ART instances can create several threads and
> these threads have the app PID. But is it possible for an app to have
> several PID simultaneously? If it is the case could you provide an
> example?

Yes, an Android application can have multiple different PIDs.

From the Android documentation:

> [Processes and threads
> overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Processes)
>
> By default, all components of the same application run in the same
> process and most applications should not change this.

But it goes on to say:

> However, you can arrange for different components in your application
> to run in separate processes, and you can create additional threads
> for any process.
>
> The manifest entry for each type of component element—,
> , , and —supports an android:process
> attribute that can specify a process in which that component should
> run....
>
> The  element also supports an android:process attribute,
> to set a default value that applies to all components.

Also (from SO post I cited above):

> You can also launch different activities under different
> taskAffinities with a newTask intent flag which will then give
> separate PIDs to those activities of same app as well.

Comment: Thanks but how can we see those multiple PIDs for each application from the strace output. Because we can run strace on each separate PID but how can we run strace on all PIDs of the same application

Comment: Q: I'm curious - if you're on Android, how are you running strace in the first place?  Android terminal?  Yes - [strace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) is per-pid.  Run [ps](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) to identify the PIDs, then run strace on each.  You can start concurrent shells, or you can run strace in the background (`&`) and redirect output (`2>&1`)

Comment: I loaded the binary strace file into the phone and i'm running strace using the adb shell

Comment: To answer your question: "Yes, it's possible for an app to have multiple PIDs".  There are plenty of tools to see if this is the case with your app - starting with "logcat".  As far as "strace" - I have no idea what you're using it for.  If you encounter problems with your particular use case, there are certainly alternatives.  I assume you're probably using Android Studio, and you're familiar with the debugger, logcat and the many other tools it provides.  I hope that answers your question(s).  Good luck!